# Store CDR database records in tables named after account code?

Tags: asterisk

Is it possible to tell asterisk to store cdr records into different tables? I'd preferably like to do it based on the account code field.

I could do a script to do this periodically but I wondered if there was a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is doable.  You didn't specify a CDR backend, and not all CDR backends are capable of this - but this is possible in cdr_adaptive_odbc.

You would set up a separate context for each table that you want to store a CDR record in, then use a filter to match on columns.  Any CDR record that does not explicitly match a filter gets discarded.  Note that the filters do support negation using the '!' character.

For example, say we have accountcode foo and accountcode bar - to be stored in tables cdr_foo and cdr_bar.  We could set this up as follows:

```
[cdr_foo]
connection=pgsql1
table=cdr_foo
filter accountcode => foo

[cdr_bar]
connection=pgsql1
table=cdr_bar
filter accountcode => bar
```

Comment: I take it that's in cdr_mysql.conf. Thanks

Comment: Nope, its not in cdr_mysql.conf.  That configuration file is for cdr_mysql, which is a deprecated module.

The configuration I posted would be in cdr_adaptive_odbc.conf.